# Replace one column of a table with another column of another table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a table with several columns Table1(Col A, Col B)

Now I have one more table with one column. Table2 (Col C)

What I want to do is:
Replace Col B of table1 with Col C of tabl 2.

Is it possible in SQL? I am using phpmyadmin to execute queries

**Why I need to do this?**
- I was playing around with the database structure and changed the type of text to integer which messed up the entries in the column
- Good thing: I have a backup excel file so now i am planning to replace the effected column to by the orginal values in the backedup excel file.

Comment: How are the two related? As in, how would you know which C form Table2 should replace which B from Table1?

Comment: they are just 2 tables. not related.

Comment: Why would you even want the data in the same table then?

Comment: So you just need random values from Table2 to be inserted into a new column on Table1? That does not make sense.

Comment: I updated the column's data type and lost the information in the table. so i want to upload the actual values again which i made backup via exporting

Comment: Table2 -Col C is the backed up column and Table 1- Col B is the effected column

Answer (score 0):

No can do.

You seem to be making an incorrect assumption, namely that the order of rows in a table is significant.  Else what's confusing some of the commenters would be clear to you: there's no information in table2 to relate it to table1.

Since you still have the data in Excel, drop table2 and re-create it with rows having the key to table1.  Then write a view to join them.  Easiest is probably to insert that join result into a third table, and then drop the first two and rename the third.